# Why is DOM document.createElement() not working?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a JavaScript file that makes a basic layout of a webpage when you `src` it into your HTML code. But there is an error. What is wrong? Let me show you some code.

```js
var z = document.createElement("p");
z.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
document.body.appendChild(z);
```

My error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

Please, don't say "do proper research". I already did! I googled and checked Stack Overflow for it. Anyone have any simple, working code snippets?

**Edit: The code is in the < head>, not the < body>!**

Comment: [it should work](https://jsbin.com/dutosinozu/edit?js,output) - we need an [mcve] to figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @VLAZ His script is in the `<head>`, not the `<body>`

Comment: Yup @CertainPerformance

Comment: Well, that's why it doesn't work, then. The head will be parsed before the body, so when the script runs there is no body. Move it out of the head or delay the execution until after the page has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks!!! Can you reopen and answer so I can accept? I really want to give you the extra reputation!